MC888 5g router with Google WiFi puck and coax extender
Very weird/specific issue here.
I'm in a rural spot and use mobile broadband. I have a 4G router currently that is about 300m from the house. It is connected to my Google WiFi router via a coax network extender and all works ok. It's double natted as the router is not in bridge mode but that has not been a problem and it means I can access the router without walking down the lane!
I've now got a 5G signal so got a ZTE MC888 to use instead. Exactly the same setup results in the Google router losing internet connection. The ZTE 888 is on the same IP range as the old router, DHCP on etc
Now here is the weirdness....when I plug the Google router directly into the ZTE 888 it works, but when I introduce the coax extenders it doesn't, even though they do nothing to the signal except pass it through and no settings are changed on the ZTE 888 router (the signal is very poor at the house hence the need for the coax extenders)
Anyone have any ideas? It's got me proper stumped..it's a real shame as the 5g signal is 5x the speed of the 4g.
Thanks

I'll answer my own question..though the answer raises another question?!
So turns out the cat 5 cable between the modem and the coax extender didn't work with the new modem but worked with the old one...but I've no idea why?  New cable sorted the issue.

cable should not exceed 100 meter. I think the old equipment was just more respectful/tolerant than the other one

Thanks for the suggestion, I'd love to know the why! Its not the cable between the coax convertors, thats coax cable and about 300m, this was the short cat 5 cable between the modem and the coax converter...just a regular cat 5 cable about 1m in length.

the reason could be a bad cable. Specially while using gigabit or faster. you need to Messure that specific cable, but it costs more as just replacing it.
